# Como tirar o fragment layout name e appcompact?

Tags: android

Olá, esses dias o meu computador estragou e eu tive que formatar e então tive que instalar os softwares para desenvolvimento Android novamente. Só que depois que eu instalei está diferente, está aparecendo fragment layout name e uma pasta appcompact que confunde tudo. Provavelmente foi uma atualização (que eu não gostei), gostaria de saber como faço para desabilitar e se não der qual a última versão do ADT Plugin que não tinha isso e o SDK. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments e um recurso muito bom disponível agora no Android para criar layout mais dinâmicos procura entender q você vai gostar

E se não me engano o appcompact e criado se você criar um projeto com API minima menor que 3.0 , ele cria para que você possa manipular actionbar em um projeto inferior a API3.0

Acho que basicamente e isso

São dois recursos interessantes e práticos